# Reinventing the Mouse sanity check

Tags: usb, mouse, fpga, intel-fpga

I'm essentially creating a new way to control the cursor on the screen.  Right now I have an Altera Stratix iv FPGA, and I'd like it to send information via USB to the computer and control the cursor.

Is this doable, and does anyone know of something similar?  What will this end up looking like?  I realize that I may have to write some code on the machine that listens over the port and moves the mouse, I'm fine with that, but is it possible to move the mouse with code that sits on the FPGA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably going to want to implement a [USB HID class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) device. The HID class is one of the simplest kinds of USB classes, and most USB kits come with an example HID device. The benefit is that your OS will already know how to talk to a HID device, so you won't need to write any OS drivers.

Comment: What if I needed to send information back to the same device from the computer?  Will that ruin this approach or will whatever I write work in tandem?

Comment: It is possible to have one USB device implement more than one USB class. So you could have HID in addition to a custom protocol (with a driver required on the host side) if you wanted. I recommend starting at [Jan Axelson's site, specificially the HID page](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm).